# disable html button based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to disable a button based on a condition in my MVC app.

I came up with:

```
@if (!item.Validated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("regionaladmin")) {
  <input type="button" class="btnvalidate" value="Validate" data-invoiceid=@item.InvoiceId /> <span>|</span>
}
else {
  <input type="button" class="btnvalidate" value="Validate" data-invoiceid=@item.InvoiceId disabled = "disabled" /> <span>|</span>
}
```

But this seems rather rough.

Can anybody suggest a better way to make this less lines?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary expression

```
<input type="button" class="btnvalidate" value="Validate" data-invoiceid=@item.InvoiceId
@( (!item.Validated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("regionaladmin")) ? "disabled" : "")
> <span>|</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using ASP.NET, no?  Why not skip the inline code and do it in your .cs file?

Markup:

```
<input type="button" ID="validate" runat="server" class="btnvalidate" value="Validate" data-invoiceid=@item.InvoiceId />
```

Code behind:

```
if (!item.Validated && HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("regionaladmin")) {
    validate.Attributes.Add("disabled","disabled");
}
```

Comment: It's MVC can something like this still be applied?

Comment: @AnonyMouse - I didn't know it was MVC; your tag just had html at the time.  In that case, you should look at Simone Vittori's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good, if you have 20 page only that's mean you will write this code in them, you should create of of the following:

An extension helper method that will write the needed HTML for you so it will be just as the following:

```
@Html.ButtonForWithRole(x=>"regionaladmin")
```

And encapsulate all your business logic in your extension method

Or make a partial view that will do the same and use the partial view but his little poor